# Send friend invite Linkedin API

Tags: api, linkedin-api

Tell me please. Can I send a request to friends in LInkedin via api?

I looked in api and there I did not find one. Tried here https://apigee.com/, but there too there is no such possibility.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn doesn't provide connection's email but still you invite them through API but the message will go into linkedIn site message box.

Try with linkedIn API how to import connection and send them message.